# How would I loop through this API data

Tags: php, pagination, limit, offset

I have an API I'm requesting data from.

The thing is I don't want to stress my application since the data set can contain tens of thousands of objects.

The way the data is returned is like this where I can specify a page limit and an offset, like limit=10 and offset=10:

```
"objects": {
    "object",
    "object2",
    //and so on....
}
"hasMore": true,
"count": 23123,
```

The count property holds the total amount of objects, and hasMore equals true if there's more objects to fetch and false if no objects left.

If hasMore equals true my assumption is that I need to make a new request with the offset equal to double my pagesize until hasMore equals false, right?

I've tried something like this, but no work since I'm left with an almost empty object with only the hasMore equal false and total count:

```
 $pageSize = 10;
 $pages = ceil(23123 / $pageSize); // total count of objects
 for ($page = 0; $page <= $pages; $page++) {
    $products = $api->get_products($page * $pageSize, $pageSize);
    var_dump(json_decode($products));
 }
```

Comment: This seems like a job for a `while` loop

Comment: it is not clear what is the issue ?

Comment: One of my concerns is if this is the "right way" to split up data from an API. Instead of stressing the server, I'd like to use some sort of pagination with limits and offsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concur with @miken32

Assuming it's `$api->getproducts( $offset, $limit )`, try this:

```
$pageSize      = 10;
$currentPage   = 0;
$hasmore       = true;

while( $hasmore === true ) {
    $currentOffset = $currentPage * $pageSize;
    $products      = json_decode( $api->get_products( $currentOffset, $pageSize ), true );
    $hasmore       = $products['hasMore'];
    processProducts( $products['objects'] );
    $currentPage++;
}
```

Comment: `$hasmore` is *not* a string. You also need to pass a truthy value to `json_decode()` in order to get an array back.

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```
$products = json_decode($products, true)

foreach ($products["objects"] as $object) {
    echo $object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to unconditionally execute the first iteration and then decide if more looping is required at the end of each iteration, use `do {} while ()`.

```
$page = 0;
$size = 10;
do {
    $products = json_decode($api->get_products($page * $size, $size));
    processProducts($products->objects);
    ++$page;
} while (!empty($products->hasMore));
```

If `hasMore` does not exist as a property of the `$products` object or is `false`, then the loop will break.